# Grunt is not working through batch file

Tags: batch-processing

When i run grunt command through manually opening the cmd and write the command then it works nicely, but the same command is not working through batch file.It shows grunt is not recognized as internal or external command.
please help me to fix this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the command you are trying to run

Comment: my command is my own application related command.I have a file createAccount.js .
From the specific directory I run "grunt createAccount".